Can The Police Ignore The Orphan Stomper?
So let's say a man walks into an orphanage and starts stomping on babies' heads, killing them. The police show up and decide that they would rather wait for him to finish stomping orphans, so that they could charge him with the most murder charges as possible. So they just fold their arms and watched him stomp. Could the police officers be held liable for negligence or charged with a crime for allowing the stomping to continue?

united-states

Could the police officers be held liable for negligence or charged
with a crime for allowing the stomping to continue?

Civil liability
The police could not be held liable in the U.S. (with the possible exception of possibly liability under state law in Vermont, which has a statutory duty to rescue). The leading case on point supporting this conclusion is Town of Castle Rock v. Gonzales, 545 U.S. 748 (2005). It basically held that police have not civil liability for failing to act to protect an individual absent facts not present in that case (e.g., a law enforcement officer has a duty to use reasonable care to protect an individual who is in the custody of the officer).
The facts of the Castle Rock case, as recounted by the U.S. Supreme Court in that case, were as follows (citations and footnotes omitted):

The horrible facts of this case are contained in the complaint that
respondent Jessica Gonzales filed in Federal District Court. (Because
the case comes to us on appeal from a dismissal of the complaint, we
assume its allegations are true.) Respondent alleges that petitioner,
the town of Castle Rock, Colorado, violated the Due Process Clause of
the Fourteenth Amendment to the United States Constitution when its
police officers, acting pursuant to official policy or custom, failed
to respond properly to her repeated reports that her estranged husband
was violating the terms of a restraining order.
The restraining order had been issued by a state trial court several
weeks earlier in conjunction with respondent’s divorce proceedings.
The original form order, issued on May 21, 1999, and served on
respondent’s husband on June 4, 1999, commanded him not to “molest or
disturb the peace of [respondent] or of any child,” and to remain at
least 100 yards from the family home at all times. The bottom of the pre-printed form noted that the reverse side
contained “IMPORTANT NOTICES FOR RESTRAINED PARTIES AND LAW
ENFORCEMENT OFFICIALS.” Ibid. (emphasis deleted). The preprinted text
on the back of the form included the following “WARNING”:
“A KNOWING VIOLATION OF A RESTRAINING ORDER IS A CRIME … . A VIOLATION
WILL ALSO CONSTITUTE CONTEMPT OF COURT. YOU MAY BE ARRESTED WITHOUT
NOTICE IF A LAW ENFORCEMENT OFFICER HAS PROBABLE CAUSE TO BELIEVE THAT
YOU HAVE KNOWINGLY VIOLATED THIS ORDER.” Id., at 1144.
The preprinted text on the back of the form also included a “NOTICE TO
LAW ENFORCEMENT OFFICIALS,” which read in part:
“YOU SHALL USE EVERY REASONABLE MEANS TO ENFORCE THIS RESTRAINING
ORDER. YOU SHALL ARREST, OR, IF AN ARREST WOULD BE IMPRACTICAL UNDER
THE CIRCUMSTANCES, SEEK A WARRANT FOR THE ARREST OF THE RESTRAINED
PERSON WHEN YOU HAVE INFORMATION AMOUNTING TO PROBABLE CAUSE THAT THE
RESTRAINED PERSON HAS VIOLATED OR ATTEMPTED TO VIOLATE ANY PROVISION
OF THIS ORDER AND THE RESTRAINED PERSON HAS BEEN PROPERLY SERVED WITH
A COPY OF THIS ORDER OR HAS RECEIVED ACTUAL NOTICE OF THE EXISTENCE OF
THIS ORDER.” Ibid.
On June 4, 1999, the state trial court modified the terms of the
restraining order and made it permanent. The modified order gave
respondent’s husband the right to spend time with his three daughters
(ages 10, 9, and 7) on alternate weekends, for two weeks during the
summer, and, “   ‘upon reasonable notice,’   ” for a mid-week dinner
visit “   ‘arranged by the parties’   ”; the modified order also
allowed him to visit the home to collect the children for such
“parenting time.”
According to the complaint, at about 5 or 5:30 p.m. on Tuesday, June
22, 1999, respondent’s husband took the three daughters while they
were playing outside the family home. No advance arrangements had been
made for him to see the daughters that evening. When respondent
noticed the children were missing, she suspected her husband had taken
them. At about 7:30 p.m., she called the Castle Rock Police
Department, which dispatched two officers. The complaint continues:
“When [the officers] arrived … , she showed them a copy of the TRO and
requested that it be enforced and the three children be returned to
her immediately. [The officers] stated that there was nothing they
could do about the TRO and suggested that [respondent] call the Police
Department again if the three children did not return home by 10:00
p.m.”
At approximately 8:30 p.m., respondent talked to her husband on his
cellular telephone. He told her “he had the three children [at an]
amusement park in Denver.” She called the police again and asked
them to “have someone check for” her husband or his vehicle at the
amusement park and “put out an [all points bulletin]” for her husband,
but the officer with whom she spoke “refused to do so,” again telling
her to “wait until 10:00 p.m. and see if   ” her husband returned the
girls.
At approximately 10:10 p.m., respondent called the police and said her
children were still missing, but she was now told to wait until
midnight. She called at midnight and told the dispatcher her children
were still missing. She went to her husband’s apartment and, finding
nobody there, called the police at 12:10 a.m.; she was told to wait
for an officer to arrive. When none came, she went to the police
station at 12:50 a.m. and submitted an incident report. The officer
who took the report “made no reasonable effort to enforce the TRO or
locate the three children. Instead, he went to dinner.”
At approximately 3:20 a.m., respondent’s husband arrived at the police
station and opened fire with a semiautomatic handgun he had purchased
earlier that evening. Police shot back, killing him. Inside the cab of
his pickup truck, they found the bodies of all three daughters, whom
he had already murdered.
On the basis of the foregoing factual allegations, respondent brought
an action under 42 U. S. C. §1983, claiming that the
town violated the Due Process Clause because its police department had
“an official policy or custom of failing to respond properly to
complaints of restraining order violations” and “tolerate[d] the
non-enforcement of restraining orders by its police officers.” The complaint also alleged that the town’s
actions “were taken either willfully, recklessly or with such gross
negligence as to indicate wanton disregard and deliberate indifference
to” respondent’s civil rights.

The Official Syllabus of the Castle Rock case summarizes the majority's ruling in the 7-2 decision that overturned the U.S. Court of Appeals for the 10th Circuit in the case as follows (citations omitted):

Respondent did not, for Due Process Clause purposes, have a property
interest in police enforcement of the restraining order against her
husband.
(a) The Due Process Clause’s procedural component does not protect
everything that might be described as a government “benefit”: “To have
a property interest in a benefit, a person … must … have a legitimate
claim of entitlement to it.” Such entitlements are created by existing
rules or understandings stemming from an independent source such as
state law.
(b) A benefit is not a protected entitlement if officials have
discretion to grant or deny it. It is inappropriate here to defer to
the Tenth Circuit’s determination that Colorado law gave respondent a
right to police enforcement of the restraining order. This Court
therefore proceeds to its own analysis.
(c) Colorado law has not created a personal entitlement to enforcement
of restraining orders. It does not appear that state law truly made
such enforcement mandatory. A well-established tradition of police
discretion has long coexisted with apparently mandatory arrest
statutes. Against that backdrop, a true mandate of police action would
require some stronger indication than the Colorado statute’s direction
to “use every reasonable means to enforce a restraining order” or even
to “arrest … or … seek a warrant.” A Colorado officer would likely
have some discretion to determine that—despite probable cause to
believe a restraining order has been violated—the violation’s
circumstances or competing duties counsel decisively against
enforcement in a particular instance. The practical necessity for
discretion is particularly apparent in a case such as this, where the
suspected violator is not actually present and his whereabouts are
unknown. In such circumstances, the statute does not appear to require
officers to arrest but only to seek a warrant. That, however, would be
an entitlement to nothing but procedure, which cannot be the basis for
a property interest.
(d) Even if the statute could be said to make enforcement “mandatory,”
that would not necessarily mean that respondent has an entitlement to
enforcement. Her alleged interest stems not from common law or
contract, but only from a State’s statutory scheme. If she was given a
statutory entitlement, the Court would expect to see some indication
of that in the statute itself. Although the statute spoke of
“protected person[s]” such as respondent, it did so in connection with
matters other than a right to enforcement. Most importantly, it spoke
directly to the protected person’s power to “initiate” contempt
proceedings if the order was issued in a civil action, which contrasts
tellingly with its conferral of a power merely to “request” initiation
of criminal contempt proceedings—and even more dramatically with its
complete silence about any power to “request” (much less demand) that
an arrest be made.
(e) Even were the Court to think otherwise about Colorado’s creation
of an entitlement, it is not clear that an individual entitlement to
enforcement of a restraining order could constitute a “property”
interest for due process purposes. Such a right would have no
ascertainable monetary value and would arise incidentally, not out of
some new species of government benefit or service, but out of a
function that government actors have always performed—arresting people
when they have probable cause. A benefit’s indirect nature was fatal
to a due process claim in O’Bannon v. Town Court Nursing Center, 447
U. S. 773, 787. Here, as there, “[t]he simple distinction between
government action that directly affects a citizen’s legal rights … and
action that is directed against a third party and affects the citizen
only … incidentally, provides a sufficient answer to” cases finding
government-provided services to be entitlements.

Also, it is worth noting that there have been a handful of cases involving analogous facts, post-Castle Rock, most notably, a federal government settlement in the Parkland shooting case, in which a large settlement has been paid by a government in a situation in which Castle Rock would seem to be a solid bar to legal liability. As explained at the link:

In their lawsuit, the families accused the FBI of negligence. They say
the bureau received tips about Cruz, including his amassing of weapons
and his desire to shoot up a school, but agents failed to intervene
and prevent the violence.
Weeks before the shooting, a tipster told the FBI that Cruz was "going
to explode," and that he "was going to slip into a school and start
shooting the place up."
Though the DOJ said the settlement "does not amount to an admission of
fault by the United States" in its statement.

Given Castle Rock and the sovereign immunity of the United States  from most negligence lawsuits except in the express circumstances where sovereign immunity is explicitly waived, see generally, here (which weren't obviously present in the Parkland shooting case), the government was very unlikely to have legal liability on the merits under the applicable law.
These rare settlements are best understood as political, rather than legal, decisions made by a government to avoid bad P.R. and to provide compensation to people who were badly injured in a case where there was a moral basis for liability, even if there wasn't a legal one.
Thus, the officers would almost certainly be fired for failing to act, but they would not have civil liability to anyone for failing to act.
Criminal liability
Criminal liability is a little more uncertain.
In the Uvalde school shooting case, in Texas, two officers, who failed to act while an active shooting was underway at the elementary school, were charged criminally with child endangerment. It isn't inconceivable that similar criminal charges could be brought in the hypothetical orphan stomping case of the question.
The Uvalade school shooting case charges were brought in June of 2024, however, so they haven't resulted in any binding legal precedents yet, even in Texas where the cases were brought.
Criminal charges were also brought against a sheriff's deputy who failed to act in the Parkland shooting case, which allowed an active school shooter to continue to kill more students. The deputy was acquitted at trial, however, so there cannot be an appeal by the prosecutors to determine if the charges had a sound legal basis.
Also, it is probably not irrelevant to the likelihood of criminal liability that both of those criminal cases against law enforcement officers, like the hypothetical, involve victims who are minors.
Other jurisdictions
The result would be different in almost every country with a civil law legal system (as opposed to a "common law" legal system), of the kind found in most of continental Europe, Latin America, and much of Africa and Asia.
For example, a Latin American human rights treaty organization has held the Castle Rock was decided in a way that abrogates international human rights obligations, and in France, coast guard officials have been threatened with criminal liability for failing to provide sufficient aid to illegal immigrants from France to the U.K. who die when their vessels en route to the U.K. sink.
I have no idea how this situation would be resolved under Islamic law, or in outlier legal systems that don't really fit any of these categories, such as the legal system of China.

Wasn't there a case of the sheriff deputy at parkland as well?

@littleadv The deputy in the Parkland case who failed to intervene during the active shooter situation was acquitted of criminal charges, and has been sued, but the lawsuit is still pending. A motion to dismiss was denied in January 2024, but that is an appealable order since it involved a claim of governmental immunity, so it won't be resolved for a long time. https://www.cbsnews.com/miami/news/judge-lawsuit-against-parkland-school-deputy-over-2018-massacre-can-go-to-trial-2/

Why did I know you'd mention Castle Rock the moment I read the first line? Castle Rock can be summarized as: "The Police has no duty to protect a particular individual. The duty is to the public at large."

@Trish "Why did I know" because you know that law as well as I do and I've probably cited it at least half a dozen times, if not more, on Law.SE (since it comes up often since it is a morally unintuitive result)?

Ayup... and of course the various youtube lawyers reiterating it again and again - It's one of the cases you don't get from your head, especially if you actually read the details.

Where in your quoting of the Castle Rock case does it say why the police weren't liable? What's the point of a restraining order if the police won't enforce it?

@Barmar The argument of the plaintiff in Castle Rock had been that the restraining order created a duty to act under state law, even though in the absence of a restraining order, the police wouldn't have been a legal duty to protect the children. SCOTUS held, however, that this wasn't sufficient to disturb the general rule that law enforcement has not duty to protect any specific individual. The SCOTUS opinion at the link spells out the analysis at greater depth.

I think it would be more helpful to us lay people if your answer summarized the SCOTUS logic in plain language rather than just restating the facts of the case. From what I can tell, they decided that "YOU SHALL USE EVERY REASONABLE MEANS TO ENFORCE THIS RESTRAINING ORDER" doesn't mean what most of us think it means.

Starting the decision with "the horrible facts of the case" is right up there with politicians who offer "thoughts and prayers" rather than meaningful legislation....

@Barmar I've added an excerpt of the court's reasoning in the case per your suggestion. FWIW, I would have been in the dissent on this case and was moderately surprised when I saw the ruling for the first time.

It's unfortunate that the Declaration of Independence is not binding law. We don't actually have a legal right to "life, liberty, and the pursuit of happiness."

@Barmar 4th, 5th, 14th amendment? LAst one reads: "nor shall any State deprive any person of life, liberty, or property, without due process of law; nor deny to any person within its jurisdiction the equal protection of the laws."

@Trish I'm referring to 'To have a property interest in a benefit, a person … must … have a legitimate claim of entitlement to it.' in the decision. They're apparently saying that the person being protected by the TRO doesn't have a legitimate claim of entitlement to personal safety.

@Barmar Strictly speaking, the property interest in the decision is a property interest in compelling the police to help them, and not in their lives, per se, which weren't taken away by the police. There would be a wrongful death lawsuit available against the perpetrator or his estate. I just concluded a lawsuit recovering damages in a similar murder-suicide case in Colorado recently.

@ohwilleke Yeah -- the problem is that remedies are seemingly only available after damage has been done, we can't count on the police to protect us. Yet it seems like that's exactly the point of a TRO. Of course, our laws are consistent with that: We can't have gun control, we can only prosecute after they shoot someone.

@Barmar Honestly, the lack of a legal basis to sue the police for failing to protect you is the best justification for an individualized right to bear arms under the Second Amendment applying to the states.

@Barmar, but we can and do have gun control - a good number of states require background checks on all gun purchases.  And yes, you can only prosecute someone after they commit a crime.  As it should be...

@MichaelHall I'm not talking about prosecuting them before the act, just preventing them from completing a bad act that's in progress. Rich people can hire bodyguards to protect them, but the rest of us depend on the police. And as for gun control, I thought "effective" was implicit.

I agree that there is be a moral imperative to stop an act in progress, but as this answer confirms, police have no obligation to pre-empt criminal acts.  Yes, I agree that "effective" is certainly implied and I don't want to turn this into a 2A debate, but enforcement of existing laws could use some improvement...  Cheers.

Coincidentally, this week's "Radiolab" on NPR (originally aired 9 years ago, then run again after Uvalde) is all about the Castle Rock case and other similar incidents. https://radiolab.org/podcast/no-special-duty-2206
